Adjunction between Posets and Toplogical Spaces
This question is from an exercise (Exercise 5.6.1 (f) of "An Introduction to Category Theory" by Harold Simmons.
The solution can be found at the publisher's web site; here is the direct link.
Here we consider a pair of contravariant functors between posets and topological spaces:
$$
\mathbf{Pos} \xrightarrow[]{\Upsilon} \mathbf{Top}, \quad
\mathbf{Top} \xrightarrow[]{\mathcal{O}} \mathbf{Pos}
$$
where $\Upsilon$ returns a space of upper sections of the underlying poset with a topology built in a former question (part (b)) and $\mathcal{O}$ returns the underlying topology directed with $\subset$.
Through a sequel of questions, we find $\mathcal{O}$ is naturally isomorphic to a homo-functor $\mathbf{Top}(\_,2)$, where $2=\{0,1\}$ is with its Sierpinski topology $\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$.
Moreover, this pair forms a contravariant adjunction (part (d).)
Within its solution, he stated:

We now use the sierpinski topology on 2 to furnish $\Pi A$ as a space, the subspace of the product space. We check that the bijection above is a homeomorphism.

and

In particular, we can replace $\mathcal{O}$ by the enriched hom-functor $\Pi = \mathbf{Pos}(_, 2)$.

Here $\Pi = \mathbf{Pos}(\_,2)$ with the standard order $0<1$.
What I do not understand are:

How do we topologize the set of monotone characters $\Pi A = \mathbf{Pos}(A,2)$?
It seems, as the phrase "the subspace of the product space" implies, the curry-ing or uncurry-ing is involved but where is it?
The last part is "we can replace $\Upsilon$ by the enriched hom-functor $\Pi = \mathbf{Pos}(_, 2)$," isn't it?

Thank you in advance!
